# How to rename files in a folder in using batch file?

Tags: batch-file, symbols

I have files exam:

```
abc de&f 1 ijk.mp3

abc de&f 2 ijk.mp3

abc de&f 3 ijk.mp3

.....
```

I want rename these files to this:

```
abc de&f xyz 1 ijk.mp3

abc de&f xyz 2 ijk.mp3

...
```

I use this command

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%x in ('dir /b *.mp3') do call :rena "%%x"

exit

:rena

set y=%~1

set y=%y:de^&f=de^&f xyz%

ren "%~1" "%y%"

goto :eof
```

But it error by "&" symbol in this line:

```
set y=%~1
```

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Basically, using the syntax `set "VAR=Value"` avoids the need of escaping, and it is probably the solution for this question...

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I have done it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.mp3" '
 ) DO CALL :rena "%%a"

GOTO :EOF

:rena
SET "original=%~1"
SET "new=%original:de&f=de&f xyz%"
ECHO REN "%sourcedir%\%~1" "%new%"
GOTO :eof
```

So I changed the names of the variables and the directory-name to scan - which is unimportant.

The key is using quotes in the `set` command - preferred in a string set to ensure trailing spaces are not assigned.

Obviously also, the `ren` command is simply `echo`ed.

Comment: Thank you. But please tell me know what "\t w o" is and what "dir /b /a-d" means. I am using this command within same folder.

Comment: `U:\sourcedir\t w o` is simply a test directory that I use. It's on my u: drive, which is a ramdrive and so I don't have to remember to clean it up. It also contains spaces in the directoryname to test that the procedure works properly on directories which contain spaces. `dir /b /a-d` means directory, in basic form (names only) but with no directorynames. I post solutions for the general case, not tailored for a specific instance. In your case, you could set `sourcedir` to `.` (meaning "the current directory") or completely omit `%sourcedir%\` throughout.